# Naming convention for constructors and destructors in C

Tags: c, constructor, naming-conventions, destructor

Suppose I have a `struct list`, and I want to provide a "constructor" and a "destructor" function. How should I name them, respectively?

```
void list__init(struct list * self);
void list__construct(struct list * self);
void list__create(struct list * self);
...

void list__done(struct list * self);
void list__destruct(struct list * self);
void list__destroy(struct list * self);
...
```

Is there an established naming convention that is predominant in the real world?

Comment: Is the construction and destruction responsible for the allocation and deallocation or just the initialisation? I prefer to mimic C++ and have `type_new()` and `type_delete()` with the `_new` returning a pointer (FWIW).

Comment: Did you know that there are C++ compilers that emit C code? Just saying...

Comment: I assume C++ is out of the question...

Comment: create/destroy, init/uninit, allocate/free... the possibilities are endless.

Comment: @hmjd I want to mimic constructors and destructors. The client is responsible for providing the memory via `self`.

Comment: Beware that the double underscore is reserve for C++. So better avoid it whenever it could be possible that your interfaces is included in C++ one  day.

Comment: @Blank So names like `list__push_back` are "unambiguous" :) I know double underscores are evil, but they seem to be the best solution I have found so far...

Comment: @FredOverflow: you can make method names unambiguous without resorting to `__` by avoiding `_` in type names, either by not separating words at all or by using CamelCase

Comment: CamelCase -> BLEARGH!!! :-P :-)

Comment: I'm not sayin' you're wrong... just that Satan uses CamelCase and that you are in league with the devil :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no generally accepted convention.

C++ has influenced peoples views in this matter, of course.

Personally, I use new() when the function performs memory allocation, init() if it does not, delete() if deallocation occurs and cleanup() if not.

Answer (score 12):

The GLib/GTK people have the created convention of using `_new` and `_free` for memory allocating constructors and destructors and `_init` and `_destroy` for non-memory allocating constructors and destructors.

The pthread library seems to mostly follow the convention of `_init` and `_destroy` for non-memory allocating ones and `_create` for memory allocating.

X11 uses `XOpenFoo` and `XCloseFoo`.

The C library itself uses `free` is used for non-memory allocating cleanups of structures like `glob_t` and `wordexp_t`.

So, I guess the answer is no, but there are definitely large groups of people who have picked particular notations in certain projects.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the following convention:

- memory allocation via `..._alloc()`
- initialization via `..._init()`
- combined allocation and initialization via `..._create()`
- release of associated resources via `..._discard()`
- release of memory via `..._dealloc()` or `..._free()`
- combined release of resources and memory via `..._destroy()`

Comment: In comparison to the accepted answer, I personally prefer the _create variant in this answer. However, I would go with _cleanup instead of _discard, and prefer _free over _dealloc (comparable to malloc/free).

Answer (score 3):

I worked in a company that used `init` / `deinit` as standard, which seemed fine. I think I've seen `init` / `fini` from more than one source, which as far as I can tell is a conceit to make the names the same length.

`pthread_mutex_init` / `pthread_mutex_destroy` (initializes in-place)

`sem_create` / `sem_destroy` (returns a new handle, but observe Posix doesn't feel the need to discriminate between a "destroy" that frees the handle and a "destroy" that destroys in-place)

`mpz_init` / `mpz_clear` (initializes in-place)

So you can probably do what you like, and nobody can reasonably complain that you're ignoring a "standard".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether it's on "object" or some "active module", I usually follow

**Object**:

```
INIT <----> TERMINATE
```

**Active module**:

```
INIT ---------> START 
 ^                ^
 |                |    
 |                v 
TERMINATE <----- STOP
```