# Should my C function take an input of a pointer and allocate, or return an allocation?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I currently have a function that will allocate an array based off of an input string. I was wondering what the best practice is with c and dynamic memory allocation in a function. Below are some options I thought of.

1.

```
type* func(char* str) {
    // preliminary stuff

    type* data = calloc(n, sizeof(type));

    // post allocation stuff

    return data;
}
```

2. 

```
void func(char* str, type** target) {
    // preliminary stuff

    *target = calloc(n, sizeof(type));

    // post allocation stuff
}
```

3. 

```
type* func(char* str, type** target) {
    // preliminary stuff

    *target = calloc(n, sizeof(type));

    // post allocation stuff

    return target;
}
```

or is there another option I don't know?

With fopen, it returns a pointer to a file that has to be closed with fclose. With strcpy, it takes an destination and source string, but you have to allocate it yourself. I'm just unsure what would be the best practice here. And is it preferred that functions do not dynamically allocate? Or is it ok if they do?

**Edit:**

I realize I that passing the target would need to be a ptr-to-ptr, so I have changed that.
I also thought of some other options.

4.

```
type* func(char* str, size_t* num_elements) {
    // preliminary stuff

    *num_elements = n;
    type* data = calloc(n, sizeof(type));


    // post allocation stuff

    return data;
}
```

5. 

```
size_t func(char* str, type** target) {
    // preliminary stuff

    *target = calloc(n, sizeof(type));

    // post allocation stuff

    return n;
}
```

Comment: `func(type* target) {  target = ` modifier _local copy_ of the pointer. The memory is lost. Did you mean `*target =`?

Comment: ...and then the parameter needs to be a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake, just changed it

Comment: If the function allocates and returns, consider using a consistent naming convention that highlights this fact (for example, starting the function name with `create_`).

Comment: All of you alternatives are plausible at the level of generality of the question.  I have seen analogues of most, maybe all of them in the wild.  Without any specific criteria on which to evaluate them, which to prefer is a matter of style and preference.

Comment: If I do have a function named ```create_``` which option would you suggest

Comment: 1. fine, but must assign return. 2. fine, but no option to assign return, 3. fine like (2) but with additional option to assign return, 4. fine, must assign return, and value at `num_elements` updated and available back in caller, 5. fine, (basically 4 reversed). At this point the question is "What form is the most convenient for my requirements and use?"

Comment: There are *many* options, some which are preferable, or better suited to RAII. The critical part is getting back to the caller with information on errors and returns. Especially in C that has no native out-of-band exceptions. Consistency is good, too. Once you use it several times, it should be more clear what the most convenient way is.

Answer (score 1):

You are tackling two separate issues here.

###### 1. Function signature

strongly depends on specific case and specific function and how this specific function should react. In case of `fopen`, yes it returns a pointer, but the *error code* is stored separately inside `errno`. For example you could:

```
enum {
  FUNC_SOMETHING_ELSE_THAT_CAN_FAIL_FAILED = -1,
  FUNC_SOMETHIGN_THAT_CAN_FAIL_FAILED = -2,
};
int func(TYPE *additional_ret) {
   if (something_that_can_fail) {
        return FUNC_SOMETHIGN_THAT_CAN_FAIL_FAILED;
   }
   if (something_else_that_can_fail) {
        return FUNC_SOMETHING_ELSE_THAT_CAN_FAIL_FAILED;
   }
   *additional_ret = something;
   return 0; // success
}
```

Then the user can differentiate using `func` return code what exactly has failed and act accordingly. You can always "flip" parameters:

```
TYPE func(int *error_code_pointer) {
   if (something_that_can_fail) {
        *error_code_pointer = FUNC_SOMETHIGN_THAT_CAN_FAIL_FAILED;
        return NULL;
   }
   if (something_else_that_can_fail) {
        *error_code_pointer = FUNC_SOMETHING_ELSE_THAT_CAN_FAIL_FAILED;
        return NULL;
   }
   return something;
}
```

This depends on *you* - how *you* want to the function to be written and how you feel it would be the best for the user for specific user-case.

However, returning an `int` with value `0` on success and non-zero on error is strongly prevalent in C programming. You should follow that convention - try to return an `int`, `0` means success, non-zero means error.

If, however, there is only a single one "thing_that_can_fail", there is no need to differentiate between error codes. In such cases, you just can return the pointer, and return `NULL` on error - in such case the function can return the pointer. Or in case you just "don't care" for error code.

###### 2. Memory ownership

is a separate topic. There are environments which do not "have" `*alloc` *at all*. Do you want your library to target such environments? Do you want to be portable? `strcpy` was designed to "work" in all environments.

Generally, to be portable, you may prefer to write functions that will work on pre-allocated memory, and let the user handle memory lifetime. So the user can, if he wants to, allocate the memory statically or in a shared memory region, or anywhere he wants to, and your function will still work with it. But that still strongly depends on the specific library/function and what specifically it does. The important part is that memory ownership is clearly documented, so that the user knows if he has to provide memory for the function or not.

```
/// @def
/// @param str some string
/// @param target preallocated memory region with at least strlen(str) + 1 bytes
/// @returns 0 on success, othwerise errro.
int func(char *str, char *target);
```

Some libraries come with `something_new` function and `something_init`, and with `something_destroy` and `something_deinit` functions, so the user can choose any combination. [Naming convention for constructors and destructors in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583908/naming-convention-for-constructors-and-destructors-in-c)

###### @edit 3. returning multiple stuff

I would go with `type *func(char* str, size_t* num_elements);` - return the stuff that has to be `free()`d later, and you can check against `NULL` if it vailed. I think the best would be to do a struct:

```
struct num {
   char *val;
   size_t nelems;
};
struct num *num_create(char *str);
// or in case error is important
int num_create(struct num **thisp, char *str);
// or/and
int num_init(struct num *this, char *str);
```

Comment: "in case of fopen, yes it returns a pointer, but the error code is stored separately inside errno" --> The standard C library does not specify setting `errno` for any `fopen` reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code to focus on the pointers.  Instead of using 'type', I am just using a character buffer.  I also show how to do with three variants and one is my preferred choice.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <string.h> // strcpy, strlen
#include <stdlib.h> // calloc

char *func1(char *str) {
  char *a_buffer = str;
  a_buffer = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(a_buffer,str);
  return a_buffer;
}


void func2(char *str, char **target) {
  *target = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(*target, str);
}

// preferred
char *func3(char *str, char *target) {
  target = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(target, str);
  return target;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char a_fixed_buffer[128] = "a fixed buffer";
    char *a_dynamic_buffer;

    a_dynamic_buffer = func1(a_fixed_buffer);
    printf("buffer is %s\n", a_dynamic_buffer);
    free(a_dynamic_buffer);

    func2(a_fixed_buffer, &a_dynamic_buffer);
    printf("buffer is %s\n", a_dynamic_buffer);
    free(a_dynamic_buffer);

    // preferred
    a_dynamic_buffer = func3(a_fixed_buffer, a_dynamic_buffer);
    printf("buffer is %s\n", a_dynamic_buffer);
    free(a_dynamic_buffer);

    return 0; //end of code
}
```